# Print out all different characters that occur in body of text

Tags: java

Java beginner here without an idea how to solve following task:

Write program which writes out all different characters that occur in body of text(35 words min).Also write out how many different characters are in text.

Example : For "We are going home" will print out  " W e a r g o i n h m " 10.

THx for help

Edit : Suppose I should post at least what i have, so here is  it even tho it doesnt do task ,but atm I cant do much better:

```
    String text = "Some text that goes here.And some more text";

    text = text.toLowerCase();

    for(int i = 0; i< text.length(); i++)
    {   
        char znak = text.charAt(i);

        for(int j = 1; j<text.length(); j++)
        {
            char znakj = text.charAt(j);

            if(text.charAt(j) != znak)  
            System.out.print(text.charAt(j));               

            else 
                continue;
        }
```

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt. Then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Consider using Sets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might wonder why your question gets downvoted. The reason for this is, that if you have homework questions you are expected to show some own work. We are happy to help if you are really stuck. So let us know do you have code to open the file, read it char by char or similar? (Usually assignments build up on previous assignments, so if you have a main loop, show them).

Comment: I put my " atempt" .thx for advice

Answer (score 1):

You scan over the character, put them in a HashSet, and you have the size().

Comment: Just one think have to clarify - you need to use `Character`  instead of `char` to put them in `HashSet`. Because collection framework doesn't support primitive type.

Comment: thx for your idea.
I  scan over them with for loop ( int i=0; i<string.lenght; i++)
but what I strugle is what to do next.
What I think might work is to set another chart chart a = string.chartAT(i), than to set another for loop to campare a with all other charaters in the string .

Comment: Too simple, really:

    Set<Character> allc = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        allc.add(s.charAt(i));
    }

    for (Character c: allc) {
        System.out.print(" " + c);
    }
    System.out.println(" -> " + allc.size());

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can make a stream from a string. Then just distinct and collect to list.

Print the list
Print the size of the list

Comment: Since "Java beginner here" I would avoid suggesting streams... but idea is nice.

Comment: Java 8 streams is the way to go to count chars or words in texts. And parallel stream will improve the performance even more.

Comment: I agree that in real world it would be good idea, but since OP seems new to Java it is better to introduce simpler concepts like loops and collections first (maybe even explain how implementations of Set works).

Comment: I know how to count charts or words in texts. 
What boggles me in this practicular sample is how to store chart after you compare it and how to avoid from that same chart being scanned again. 
I have update OP with some code which scans thru string but with exact problems I stated few in sentence above.
I have na idea to setup special array where to store all charts and print them out . You think that might work ?